# Looking for a goodness-of-fit measure for fitting a model to an image

Tags: normal-distribution, goodness-of-fit, fitting, image-processing, anderson-darling-test

I am trying to fit a model to a noisy image. After fitting, I would like to have some way of assessing the quality of the fit (i.e. whether there are any systematic deviations of the model from the data). My first thought was to test the distribution of the deviations between the model and the data for normality. By visual inspection I can see that the deviations are non-normal before fitting, and pretty much normal after. However, when I use an Anderson-Darling test to get a quantitative measure of the significance it still seems significantly non-normal (A^2 = ~100), probably because of the large number of data points (~1200x1200 pixels).

Is there some other test that is more suitable for measuring the quality of fit to an image?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What would testing for normality accomplish?

Comment: @Dave I want to get a measure of the quality of the fit, i.e. when the fit is good, the deviations between the data and the model should be normally distributed (only noise). When the deviations are non-normal, the fit is not good enough yet.

Comment: 1) What’s wrong with other kinds of noise? // 2) What about a normal distribution with a huge variance? To me, that indicates a poor fit. Perhaps you have a definition of “fit” that differs from how I would use the word.

Comment: @Dave Not sure what other kinds of noise you are referring to. The image in question is a microscopy image to which I am fitting a model consisting of gaussian functions. I am assuming that noise arising from measurement inaccuracies etc are normally distributed and that inaccuracies in the fit (e.g. the positions, intensity etc of the guassian functions of the model) lead to systematic deviations which are non-normal.

Comment: Why are non-normal deviations undesirable, and why is any kind of normal deviation distribution desirable?